# Building modular asp core angular application

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, design-patterns, architecture

I'm here because I'm facing an issue. At our company, we decided to build an ASP core with angular front end application. We want to publish it to our integrators but they may want to add specific development on their side on our applications for specifics clients need. How is it possible for them to add code to our application? On the front end part (angular) as well as to the backend part (ASP core) knowing that we will give them a compiled application. We do not want them to have access to the source code ...

It's like for odoo for example you can add pluggin to it. We would like to do something similar. Do you guys know how it is possible in ASP core + Angular 7 ?

Thanks in advance,
Looking forward for your advices

A. MOULAY

Answer (score 0):

The part you said you want to ask them to work for it and not give them source code, I assume you mean you want them to work for front-end but not to have access to back-end , if yes:

We have done exactly the same for React, the concept is your Angular App seats in \ClientApp folder
You can move the the folder to a new folder and initiate a git init push it to a github or any git repository then add it as

```
dotnet new angular -o my-new-app
cd my-new-app\ClientApp

git init .
git add .
git commit "initial commit"
git remote add origin https://GITURL
git push -u origin master

cd ..
rm -rf ClientApp

git init .
git add .
git commit -m "Initial project commit"

git submodule add https://GITURL ClientApp
```

Then you can launch the project as usual.

Now if you want to give them access to back-end you can compile the DLL codes and place them in the `build` folder along side of Angular code.

You can also upload your back-end project to a staging server where they can make request to and enable `CORS` to `http://localhost:5000` where they will run Angular locally to be able to make request to `https://staging-url.com`

Add CORS:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(AllowedOriginPolicy,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:5000"
                    )
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    ;
                });
            });
```

Hope it helps
Cheers